# Volume get current of page Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, webkit

I'm looking for HTML5 / JS API that can control or detect volume of page/browser tab.

I'm trying to build test page that playing a lot of players like flash player html5 player and even an iframe player that i can't know how i get the video element.

i want to detect if the page have volume in some time and detect it.

I'm trying to detect it because sound violation on sites from ads.

Answer (score 0):

This ought to do what you wanted, it reduces volume of HTML5 video elements, iframes and Audio objects.

```
let vids = document.getElementsByTagName("video");
let iframes = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
let obj = document.getElementsByTagName("object");

vids.forEach((vid) => {
    vid.volume = 0;
});

iframes.forEach((f) => {
    f.setAttribute("volume", "0");
})

obj.forEach((o) => {
    o.volume = 0;
});
```

Comment: sorry but your solution not working and even not what i'm asked for.
I'm looking for something like API that listen to the audio buffer array on the page and know that the page is playing some sound in current time.

Comment: I am really sorry 'bout that, guess I didn't get the question right. Can you just send me the link to the page? So that I can help you out

Comment: actually i'm developed it like third party scripting so i don't have really page, i'm developed it on my local and load some videos and audios from all of the kinds like youtube and html tags.

Comment: Can you be more informative? I can help you if you show me some code